# Nav menu bleeds out of container

Tags: html, css

Morning again...,

Sorry to bother everyone but I need more help... I haven't done any real coding in ages so here goes...

I'm trying to make a horizontal navigation menu, here's my html

```
<nav>
<ul id="navmenu">
   <li><a href="" title="" class="selected">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">Link 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="" title="">Link 5</a></li>
<ul>
<nav>
```

now I have the following CSS

```
/* menu */
ul#navmenu{ 
    border-top:1px solid #FFF;
    background:#e60000;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left:30px;
}

ul#navmenu li{
    display:inline;

}

ul#navmenu li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    /*
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    */
    padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

ul#navmenu li a.selected{
    color:#e60000;
    text-decoration:none;
    /*
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    */
    padding:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

I want the links to sit in the center of the Li and look something like this:

[image]

However the containing UL doesn't seem to contain the LIs, they bleed out of the container. I've played around with overflow and line heights but nothing seems to work... here's a worst case scenario...

[image]

does any one have any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u8XeA/9/ This kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give display:block to your `<a>` because `<a>` in an `inline` element so, `inline` element not take `vertical margin`, `vertical padding`, `width` & `height`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/T8eNe/2/

but first close your `UL` & `NAV`

Comment: Do you mean inline-block... Thanks anywway I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: That is not the issue, the problem is that the containing element is not expanding to the size of its child.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I would close the `<ul>` and `<nav>` tags correctly, then check to make sure that the parent containers are floated left.

Answer (score 0):

Give `inline-block` to your anchor

```
ul li a { display: inline-block; }
```